# update replaces all the columns in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am passing the post object to update my post but To my surprise when I try to edit a single post all my posts are been replaced with the edited values (image or text) that I entered when trying to edit.

### Postcontroller

```
 public function update(Post $id){
    
 $data = request()->validate([
    'about' => 'required',
    'image' => '',

  ]);

  if(request('image')){
    $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads','public');
    $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(500,500);
  
    $image->save();

    $imageArray = ['image' => $imagePath];

  }
  auth()->user()->posts()->update(array_merge( $data, $imageArray ?? [] ) );
  $user = Auth::guard('web')->id() ;
  
  return redirect()->route('home',['user'=>$user]);
}
```

### route

```
Route::get('/post/edit/{post}', 'PostController@edit')->name('post.edit'); 
Route::patch('/p/update/{id}', 'PostController@update')->name('post.update');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code will be updating all posts for this authenticated user.

in order to fix this issue :

```
Route::get('/post/edit/{post}', 'PostController@edit')->name('post.edit'); 

Route::patch('/post/edit/{post}', 'PostController@update')->name('post.update');
```

and in your controller

```
public function update(Post $post){
    
     // validation code here

     // image upload code

    // update your database

    $post->update([

        //update database fields

     ]);
  
  return redirect('home');
}
```